# How change read/write permissions on IIS FTP using C#?

Tags: c#, iis, permissions, ftp

I create subfolders with C# under a write only root folder in a number of IIS FTP sites (multiple Servers 2008-2019).  When I create the subfolder, it inherits the write-only "FTP Authorization" from it's root.  How to I change the newly created subfolder's FTP Authorization to read/write with C#?

Comment: Why??? IIS is suppose to be secure and not allow Guest Users Access to the file system.  You should only allow users to put files on a separate Network Drive (not on IIS) that allows Guest to read and write.

Comment: Why shouldn't be a prerequisite to getting an answer.  They are all internal users so this doesn't have to be super secure. I just want to stop users (using a specific logon/password) from casually browsing a list of subfolders they might happen to see when they log on.

Comment: Just a good practice not to fool around with permissions on a Secure Server.  You would need admin privileges to make your folder read/write by the GUEST Group.  I think it is just better to mount a Network Drive on IIF and make the Network drive read/write and make the root folder for FTP on the Network Drive.

Comment: In C# you can use the managed API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration?view=iis-dotnet But if you want sample code, you probably should use a search engine.

Comment: jdweng, I'm not referring to the file privileges, rather the FTP Authorization Rules in the FTP server.  Also not sure why a network drive would be any different than one of the hard drives if both are exposed to IIS.  Lex, I've been trying to Google it but can't find how to change authorization on a single folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I added the FTP Authorization Rule to the IIS FTP site on a specific path.

```
            using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
            {
                Configuration config = serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();
                ConfigurationSection authorizationSection = config.GetSection("system.ftpServer/security/authorization", "FTP/LDNClient/Reports/" + itm["ftpClientName"]);
                ConfigurationElementCollection authorizationCollection = authorizationSection.GetCollection();

                ConfigurationElement addElement = authorizationCollection.CreateElement("add");
                addElement["accessType"] = @"Allow";
                addElement["users"] = @"LDNClient";
                addElement["roles"] = @"";
                addElement["permissions"] = @"Read, Write";
                authorizationCollection.Add(addElement);

                serverManager.CommitChanges();
            }
```

Where "FTP/LDNClient/Reports/" + itm["ftpClientName"] was the path I needed to update.